# Android: allocate a graphic once and move it around on the screen without rewriting pixels

Tags: android, memory-management, android-ndk, rendering, android-source

I have a Google Pixel 4, rooted, and I have the AOSP code building successfully. Inside an Android app, I'd like to gralloc an extra-large area of memory (probably 4x as large as the 1080x2280 screen) and draw a simple graphic (for example, a square) into the middle of the buffer. Then, on each frame, I just want to slide the pointer around on the buffer to make it look like the square is moving around on the screen (since the rest of the buffer will be blank).

I'm not sure if this is feasible. So far, I have a completely native Android app. At the beginning of android_main(), I malloc a region 4x as large as the screen, and I draw a red square in the middle. On each frame, I call

```
ANativeWindow_lock()
```

to get the pointer to the gralloced memory, which is accessed in ANativeWindow_Buffer->bits. Then I use memcpy to copy pixels from my big malloced buffer into the bits address, adjusting the src pointer in my memcpy call to slide around within the buffer and make it seem like the square is moving around on the screen. Finally, I call

```
ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost()
```

to release CPU access and post the buffer to the display.

However, I'm trying to render as fast as possible. There are 2462400 pixels (2 bytes each) for the screen, so memcpy is copying 5MB of data for each frame, which takes ~10ms. So, I want to avoid the memcpy and access the ORIGINAL pointer to the dma_buf, or whatever it is that Gralloc3 originally allocates for the GraphicBuffer (the ANativeWindow is basically just a Surface which uses a GraphicBuffer, which uses GraphicBufferMapper, which uses GrallocMapper in gralloc). This is complicated by the fact that the system appears to be triple-buffering, putting three gralloced buffers in BufferQueue and rotating between them.

By adding log statements to my AOSP build, I can see when Gralloc3 allocates buffers and how big they are. So I can allocate extra-large buffers. But it's manually adjusting the pointers and having that reflect on the display where I'm getting stuck. ANativeWindow_lock() gets a copy of the original pointer to the pixel buffer, so I figured if I can trace that call all the way down, then I can find the original pointer. I traced it down into hardware/interfaces/graphics/mapper/3.0/IMapper.hal and IAllocator.hal, which are used by Gralloc3 to interact with memory. But I don't know where to go after this. The HAL file is basically a header that's implemented by some other vendor-specific file, I guess....

[Checking out ANativewindow_lock() using Android Studio's CPU profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNHy3.png)

Based on this picture, it seems like some QtiMapper.cpp file might be implementing the HAL. There are a few files called QtiMapper, in hardware/qcom. (I'm guessing I should be looking in the sm8150 folder because the Pixel 4 uses Snapdragon 855.) Then lower down, it looks like the IonAlloc::CleanBuffer and BufferManager::LockBuffer might be in the gr_ files in hardware/qcom/display/msmxxxx/gralloc folders. But I can't be sure where the calls are being routed exactly because if I try to modify or add log statements to these files, I get problems with the AOSP build. Any directions on how to mod these would be very helpful, too. If these are the actual files being used by the system, it looks like I could possibly use them for my app because I can see the ioctl and mmap calls in them.

Using the Linux Direct Rendering Manager, I was able to write directly to the display in a C file by shutting down SurfaceFlinger and mmapping some memory. See my demo [here](https://github.com/serviceberry3/android_drm_dumb). So if I shut down the Android framework, I can accomplish what I want to do. But I want to keep Android up, because I'm looking to use the accelerometers and maybe other APIs in my app. (The goal is to use the accelerometer readings to stabilize text on the display as fast as possible.) It's also annoying because starting up the display server again does some kind of reboot.

First of all, is what I want to do even worth it? It seems like it should be, because the display on the Pixel can refresh every 10 milliseconds, and  taking the time to copy the pixel memory is pointless in this case.
Second of all, does anyone know of a way I can, within my app, adjust the low-level pointer to the pixel buffer in memory and still make it push to the display?

Comment: What do you really want to do? The question is too long but the goal and what you are already doing is not very clear.

Comment: ANativeWindow_Buffer already give you bits/width/height/stride, you can modify any pixel in ANativeWindow_Buffer. Then what else do you want?